# How to calculate the mode of an array stored in a single cell in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm new to excel, trying to calculate the mode of an array, but that array is stored in a single cell.
For example, I'm storing an array(0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,4) into cell A1 and trying to find the mode of that array. I tried MODE(A1) function, but it seems doesn't work. Is there any good recommendation? I heard it can be achieved by VBA, but I'm a noob to excel, is there any good and simple tutorial could achieve this goal? Appreciate if someone could help with this, thx:)

Comment: you can't really store an array in a single cell. You should store it in a named formula and then use mode on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a secret function called Evaluate that can take a formula constructed from concatenated strings and produce a result equivalent to that formula being used on a worksheet.

In your case, you want to build a formula that treats your string of delimited numbers as an array of real numbers so the target would look like this.

```
=MODE(0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,4)
```

A User Defined Function can bring this functionality to the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Function arrayMode(str As String)

    arrayMode = Application.Evaluate("MODE(" & str & ")")

End Function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypUkL.png)

Evaluate can also be accessed through a Defined Name. Select B2 then choose Formulas, Defined Names, Define Name. Give it a name (e.g. ARRMODE) and use the folllowing for the Referes to:

```
=Evaluate("MODE("&$A2&")")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wslP8.png)

Click OK.

Use ARRMODE like a worksheet function. The reference to the cell in column A on the same row is built in.

```
=ARRMODE
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ny7p.png)

Answer (score 0):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999)),"")
```

and copy across.  Then in **A3** enter:

```
=MODE(2:2)
```

[image]

*(You can avoid all the "helper" cells by using the EVALUATE() function)*